# How to get values directly from Excel sheet which have the keys in property files

Tags: java, excel

By using Java code, How to get values directly from Excel sheet which have the keys in property files?my question is:

i have a xyz_en_US.properties file.This property file contains keys and values of English Language.
now i also have an Excel Sheet which is having keys and values (i.e values alone transulated to spanish and the keys remain in English).

Tell me how to write (java) utility source code in eclipse to retrive the spanish value to the corresponding English key, and i need that key and value store in separete file called resourcebundle.java

is this possible using arraylist and hashmap..?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Are you developing a web application, mobile application or console application?

Comment: pls tell me how to do?

Comment: @user2511966 : here's a suggestion. 1)convert the excel to csv 2) import into database 3)do select query

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to read the excel file. [Here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/) is snippet to help you out.

```
try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

    //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

    //Get first sheet from the workbook
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        //For each row, iterate through each columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    file.close();
    FileOutputStream out = 
        new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By the way, just curies to know why excel sheet for i18n, I am sure there should be some reason. In my opinion, you can use properties file it self. Like xyz_es_ES.properties. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/internationalization.shtml).

Comment: ya sir, u are right.! i too coded by refering those topics.but i feel like converting the proeperty file to spanish is done manually. then that spanish bundle is retrived by using getbundle(); but i dont want to do like that bcoz 1000 of labels in it.(also my higher authority not expecting it) so thinking to map en_US keys to the es_ES(spanish)values and then maped new keyvalues parirs are stored in the new file as resourcebundle.java.The code which u gave is working like retriving all the keyvalues of excel sheet alone. there is no mapping is done with en_US properties and Excelsheet file.

Comment: please tell me how to put them in arraylist or hashmap?

Comment: can u tell me how to fetch the each values in excelsheet which matches keyvalues of property file.